# can not load lifecycle mapping metadata for maven project. Cause: Cannot parse version range: [,)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, pom.xml

Hi i downloaded new version of Eclipse which is 2022-06. Then i tried to create a maven project, but that displayed 2 errors. 2 of them were plugins. Eclipse added those plugins automatically. But now it display 1 new error which is;
Cannot load lifecycle mapping metadata for maven project MavenProject: mobileTests:mobileTests:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT @ C:\Users\oguzhan.k\eclipse-workspace\mobileTests\pom.xml Cause: Cannot parse version range: [,)

[new error ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CAil.png)

Note: I searched on google but could not find anything about parse version range. Could anyone help me please?

Comment: Do not use images please post the text...and also the pom file...

Comment: As of https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependency_Version_Requirement_Specification the [,) version is not valid. Make sure your version is at least 0.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted jdk and eclipse and installed eclipse again. Problem resolved. Thank you all.